# Is online Continuous Wavelet Transform possible?

Tags: wavelet, time-frequency, real-time, cwt

I have recently created a [real-time STFT](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/83477/62730) with 50% overlap.

[image]

I wanted to know if this window-based is possible for scalogram, especially continuous wavelet transform. I haven't found anyone implementing it real-time.

Also, if it is possible, does one need to compute the CWT of the whole window signal or simply a portion of it, like in a recursive way. I started learning wavelets and I look forward to any hints.

Answer (score 1):

Whether it's "real-time" depends on sampling rate. What's true is that most implementations fall short for realistic $f_s$.

I am currently working on CWT that will be faster than any other I know of, best case by several times. Though, it may be a while until it's open-sourced.

An often overlooked point is, CWT has `hop_size` just like STFT. Especially if using a scalogram (modulus), there's very little to lose from `hop_size=2` or `4`, and sometimes we can do `100+`. This is implemented easily with [Fourier-domain subsampling](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/74734/50076):

```
ifft(a * b)[::2] == ifft((a * b).reshape(2, -1).mean(axis=0))
```

which reduces FFT size by `hop_size`. The relevant question is, what `hop_size` is safe? This can be measured directly, as discussed in [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/80920/50076). Note, perfect inversion is possible for some CWT with complex-valued outputs and `hop_size>1`, but max permissible `hop_size` is fairly small and the inversion algorithm not straightforward. However, we don't need complex for inversion; inversion is [still possible](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/78531/50076) within a global phase-shift.

Another major slowdown is in low-support wavelets, which are better off with [overlap-add/overlap-save](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Overlap%E2%80%93add_method).

Putting all these together elevates max supported $f_s$ significantly.

Comment: Is there a way to determine this *realistic* $f_s$? Is there a way to know the big-$O$ notation of CWT?

Comment: @EddyPiedad If it processes 1 second of data in 1 second, it's "real-time" with 1 sec latency. What qualifies as "real-time" varies by application, sometimes we want 1 sec in 0.001 sec.