# Comparison of WVD vs STFT Spectral analysis in the presence of Noise

Tags: matlab, signal-analysis, noise, time-frequency

This question is an extension to the question about WVD vs STFT originally posted [Here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/86211/wigner-ville-distribution-wvd-vs-stft-for-spectral-analysis/86287?noredirect=1#comment182690_86287). During the QA it was pointed out that the WVD only works for noiseless signals.

To test that out I created a simple chirp signal in MATLAB and compared WVD spectrograms at different SNRs.

Below is the time-domain signal on the left and the WVD corresponding WVD on the right for 25dB SNR:

[image: Time-Domain Chirp Signal and WVD at 25dB SNR]

Below is for the 0dB SNR case:

[image: Time-Domain Chirp Signal and WVD at 0dB SNR]

Even at 0dB SNR the presence of chirp is still visible in the WVD spectrogram, is MATLAB doing any other post-processing as well? and is the WVD really useless for time-frequency analysis of real-world signals?

Comment: I suggest checking if there's windowing by default in the implementation, and asking separately about WVD's interferences, which'll shed light on this question as STFT doesn't have this problem.

Comment: Ok, ill check that out, kindly elaborate WVD's interferences?

Comment: you can detect signals below noise level, provided they have strong enough autocorrelation, so even when noise stronger that weak signal, noise does no autocorrelate, yet a correctly designed chirp may be detectable. OFDM-based systems also exhibit this strength.