# Wigner-Ville distrubution on large data signal analysis

Tags: fft, matlab, signal-analysis, python, spectrogram

I have a touch signal on a plate recorded with 3 accelerometers with a sample rate of 150kHz over a duration of 5 seconds (so 750k samples). The goal is to localize the position of the touch in the end. But for that, I need to separate the reflections from the direct wave. And therefore need to do some signal analysis.
I have read some papers about [structural health monitoring](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0964-1726/16/2/014/meta) using where they analyze the data using Wigner-Ville distribution (WVD). I wanted to try that as well but I struggle to get it to work in either Matlab or Python, where I get a memory error since the data is so large (and the function depends on a double fft). I have tried to look at the interesting part of the signal, but even that can be up to 2 seconds which also gives the same error.
Is it so that WVD only works on small samples of data?
Also, are there other methods that I should try for signal analysis? I have tried spectrogram which works nicely. And scaleograms which worked ok-ish.

Comment: An improvement over WVD is [synchrosqueezing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/71399/50076). Small comparison [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/86287/50076).

Comment: I'd recommend looking at @OverLordGoldDragon's suggestion. The WVD is a dead-end for most applications. Looks pretty, but ... has problems. If you want a C implementation of the WVD, [this C code](https://github.com/kootsoop/ccg) does it.